# Is a question which asks for "only guidance" instead of "straight answers" on topic?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

This one I honestly don't know. There is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22301695/1016716) which explains a problem, and the problem itself is straightforward enough and on topic, so that's OK, but then the poster asks literally for "only guidance and no straight answers".

Should we honour that? I mean, not that I'm against giving people guidance and hints and links rather than immediately handing them the complete source code on a platter, but isn't this question taking it a bit to far? Isn't this, in other words, primarily opinion based?

Comment: You are free to post a straight answer *anyway*. I'd just remove that part (it is noise really). The question and answers are supposed to be useful for others besides the OP, after all.

Comment: Give him whatever you like as long as it complies with the site's standards. It's up to him to choose what he takes away from it, we're not his teachers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In practice, the answerers get to decide what scope their answers have (provided their answers generally meet site guidelines), and the question is otherwise fairly typical for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Accepted because this is the best answer so far...